# How calculate data from database in R (such as mean, median, etc)

Tags: r, postgresql

For my project i have to calculate data in R from database PostgreSQL. But in R my data can't be calculated because it is read as string. When i tried to convert it into numeric or double. It's error. 
Here's my code in R

```
 > myTable<-"SELECT DISTINCT
+ round(avg(finalcall),2)
+ FROM kpidetail
+ where finalcall is not null AND priority like 'call'
+ group by agentname"
> data0<-dbGetQuery(con,myTable)
> data0
   round
1  91.56
2  88.72
3 100.00
4  70.00
5  95.00
> mean(data0)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(data0) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> dataj<-as.numeric(data0)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> mean(unlist(asnumeric(data0)))
Error in unlist(asnumeric(data0)) : could not find function "asnumeric"
> dataj<-unlist(as.double(data0))
Error in unlist(as.double(data0)) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> dataj<-as.double(data0)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I've already tried everything. But still, it didn't work at all. Any help?Thankyou in advanced..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `dbGetQuery()` appears to be returning a list, one of whose element is the column `round` from the SQL result set.  You can access this `round` column from the list and then get the calculation you want (e.g. mean):

```
mean(as.numeric(data0$round))
```